# Fetching the employee tasks list from SAP ByD via OData API

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform, sap-business-bydesign

In SAP Business ByDesign (SAP ByD), a project can have multiple tasks and each task can have assigned multiple employees. So a single user has a list of tasks to book time on.

In the SAP ByD UI, you can select an employee and see all the assigned tasks. I would like to fetch that via the OData API. I started to click together some OData Services.

I have an Endpoint that allows me to filter for an employee:

```
https://my1234567.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cust/v1/employees/EmployeeCollection?$format=json&$filter=EmployeeID eq '1234567'
```

With that, I can fetch information about an employee.
And I have an Endpoint to fetch ProjectTasks:

```
https://my1234567.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cust/v1/project/ProjectTaskCollection?$format=json
```

That collection contains always a reference to the project.
And I have a ProjectParticipant collection that tells me which user is a member of which project:

```
https://my1234567.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cust/v1/project/ProjectParticipantCollection?$format=json
```

And I can filter that ProjectParticipant collection by employee ID. With that I know which projects a user has assigned. But that does not tell me which exact tasks the user has assigned in the project. This last piece of the puzzle is missing.

I'm very new to SAP. If somebody can give me a hint for the right data model or API, I would be very thankful.